# Deleting items from database through table

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

[image]

I have made a table in html which receives database entries. Now I want to be able to edit and delete entries. So if I click the X button the selected row must be deleted. I know I need to do this by an sql query so the table changes according to database entries. But how can I do this since it needs to know which row belongs to that particular delete button?

```
<div id="customers">
<table id="customerTable">
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>Company</td>
<td>Adress</td>
<td>Wijzig</td>
<td>Verwijder</td>
</tr>
<?php
    //connect to database
    include_once('mysql_connect.php');

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("etn207") or die(mysql_error());

    // SQL query
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer";

    // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    // Loop the recordset $rs
    // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

       // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row
       echo '<tr>'; 
       echo '<td>'."<center>".$row['firstname']."<br>"."</center>".'</td>'; 
       echo '<td>'."<center>".$row['lastname']."<br>"."</center>".'</td>'; 
        echo '<td>'."<center>".$row['company']."<br>"."</center>".'</td>';
        echo '<td>'."<center>".$row['adress']."<br>"."</center>".'</td>';  
        echo '<td>'."<center>".'<img src="images/edit.png" width="20px" height="20px" border=0>'."<br>"."</center>".'</td>';   
        echo '<td>'."<center>".'<img src="images/delete.png" onClick="" width="20px" height="20px" border=0>'."<br>"."</center>".'</td>';    
        echo '</tr>'; 
      }



    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();

?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can make for every button a form or you use ajax

Comment: Be sure to avoid the SQL injection trap... Also, mysql_* is deprecated. Use mysqli_ or even more prefereably PDO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass id as a hidden value and use that to delete that particular row

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_to_be_deleted" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

Now simply retrieve this id on submit and delete the row from the database

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id_to_be_deleted" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
   <input type="submit" name="delete_row" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete_row'])) {
   $id = $_POST['id_to_be_deleted'];
   if(!mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = $id")) {
     echo mysqli_error($connection);
   } else {
      //redirect $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I am kind of new to php, could you hint me on where exactly to place that piece of code? I don't know which id the $id corresponds too. Is it also possible to use that X image like above instead of a submit button?

Comment: @DaViDa Insttead of images use a submit button for now, retrieve the id for each entry, or say a unique id to refer that particular row in the database, and than use that value in hidden field, and than delete try to delete the entry, once you are done, you can use `background-image` property in CSS to style your submit button as red 'X' image :)

Comment: Thanks i'll try it!! I don't know I didnt do it!

Answer (score 1):

Your database records most probably have a unique identifier (primary key or so); Use this unique identifier when creating the link on your delete button :

```
  echo '<a href="deleterecord.php?id=' . $yourUniqueidentifier . '"><img src="images/delete.png"></a>'
```

You should use other advice for your code too, like use CSS and not the "center" tag, maybe use AJAX to delete the record without a complete postback, use a hash in your querystring to avoid unauthorized deletion of records and so on, but that's not the point here :-)